# Setting the horizontal alignment of JTextField in a loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, alignment, jtextfield

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.util.Random;

   public class Excercise24_19 extends JFrame
   {
     private static int[][] grid = new int[10][10]; //creates a grid

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {


     Excercise24_19 frame = new Excercise24_19(); //creates the frame

     frame.setTitle("Excercise 24_19"); //title of window
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //sets location to middle of screen
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true); //displays the window
   }

   public Excercise24_19()
   {
     createMatrix(); //creates matrix of numbers inside "grid"
     setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10)); //sets a 10 x 10 layout
     String temp; //creates a temp variable to hold number's as string

     for(int i = 0; i < grid.length-1; i++)
     {
       for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length-1; j++)
         {
           temp = "" + grid[i][j] + "";
           matrix.add(new JTextField(temp, 2));
         }
     }
   }

   public static void createMatrix()
   {
     Random myRand = new Random();
     for(int i = 0; i < grid.length-1; i++)
      {
        for(int j = 0; j < grid.length-1; j++)
        {
          grid[i][j] = myRand.nextInt(2);
        }
  
      }

   }
 }
```

PROBLEM: I must create a 10x10 grid with random numbers and use JTextField so that I can change the numbers on the spot. The program must then find the biggest block (Algorithm of O(n^2) complexity) of 1's in the matrix and highlight them red.

Not implemented yet are the listeners or buttons for the other part of this program, and code that finds the largest block of 1's.

> My problem is how to i center the text on the JTextFields? Its bothering me because I am not creating variable names for the textfields but I don't see how I am suppossed to center the text inside using ".setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);"
>
> Also will I be able to create listeners for the textfields in case i do change the numbers.

If it helps this is what the end program is suppsed to look like:

[image]

This is what my program looks like now:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: In the line `matrix.add(new JTextField(temp, 2));` there is an error because you didn't define `matrix`.

Comment: took out the line where I added a frame called matrix. I took out the frame and added them straight to Excercise24_19()

Comment: Whatever you did, your code does not compile.

Comment: It does for me, I will provide an edit for the solved code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the text field a variable name if you want to change its settings. Change this line:

```
matrix.add(new JTextField(temp, 2));
```

to these lines:

```
JTextField text = new JTextField(temp, 2));
text.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
matrix.add(text);
```

Comment: I tried that before but I guess I didnt try it after I fixed my random generator! Thank you!